# How to write the Adeles over $\mathbb{Q}(i)$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, valuation-theory

What do these adeles look like over $\mathbb{Q}(i)$?  These are simply fractions where the numerator and denominator are allowed to have the number $i = \sqrt{-1}$.  The elements look like:

$$  \left\{ \frac{a + bi}{c+di}: a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Z}, \text{ but } c+di \neq 0  \right\}$$

For now I am sweeping under the rug all the details about how we can enumerate all these fractions, e.g. by the Calkin-Wilf tree.

Today's question is about the Adeles over $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ and how to write them down if we stuck with the rationals:

$$ \mathbb{A} = \{(x_\infty, x_2, x_3, x_5, \dots, )  : \text{"most" } |x|_p = 1\} \subset  \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{Q}_2 \times \mathbb{Q}_3 \times \mathbb{Q}_3 \times \dots $$

Here **most** here means all but finitely many, so the adeles $\mathbb{A}$ are a **restricted product** over all $p$-adic numbers, $\mathbb{A} = \prod' \mathbb{Q}_p$.

If we work over the extension field $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ there are other primes.  Certain primes split (such as $5 = (2+i)(2-i)$) and others ramify  (such as $2 = (1+i)(1-i)$).  Are the adeles "just" the product over all the Gaussian primes then?

$$ \mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q}(i)} = \prod'_{p = 4k+3} \mathbb{Q}_p \times  \prod'_{a^2 + b^2 = p} \mathbb{Q}_{a+bi}$$

Do we have to include both $a+bi$ and $a - bi$?

Comment: For a number field $k/\mathbb{Q}$, we have $A_k = A_\mathbb{Q} \otimes k$. This follows (with a bit of work) from the fact that $\sum_{w|v} [k_w:\mathbb{Q}_v] = [k:\mathbb{Q}]$ for a fixed place $v$ of $\mathbb{Q}$. Unwinding that should give you an explicit form for $\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q}(i)}$.

Comment: @anomaly if I understand correctly than $\mathbb{Q}_5 \otimes \mathbb{Q}(i) = \mathbb{Q}_{2+i} \oplus \mathbb{Q}_{2-i}$ ? And a similar story for $p = 13 = 2^2 + 3^2$ ?  The case $p = 2+i$ seems funny... it's probably not true that $\mathbb{Q}_2 \otimes \mathbb{Q}(i) = \mathbb{Q}_{1+i} \oplus \mathbb{Q}_{1-i}$

Comment: That is correct.  $\Bbb Q_2$ would remain a single copy of $\Bbb Q_{1+i}$, but the ideal 2 would ramify into $(1+i)^2$.